# Functions comes blank in the front end from express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I created a module that exports a function. Im my express server, im trying to send this function to the front end, but it is coming blank.
Im using Axios API to get the data in the front end.

Im very newb with NodeJs and Express.

This is my code:

```js
// Back End
function myFunction(){
    console.log("did work");
}
app.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        randomData: randomData,
        myFunction: myFunction
    });
    res.end();
});

// Front End
axios.get("/getData").then(e=>{  
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

This is the data ta i get in the front end:

[image: data that i get]

Comment: Hi Luis, functions arent sent from the backend - you can however use express to generate a JS file and send the file to the frontend and use it. Or you can send javascript as text and convert it to javascript on the frontend, but this is really bad practice... i've never delved into how advertisements are done but I would find a tutorial online and follow one of those. they should describe a workflow for sending JS and consuming it in the frontend.

Comment: You can't send a function object to the front-end.  What is it you're trying to accomplish here?  You could send code as text.  You could run the function and send the result, etc...

Comment: Thanks for both of you, im just learning and i found the res.json function that could send data to the frontend and i have some js fies that i thought that i could send to it. I thought of strygifying the function but i would like a cleaner way, but seem theres no scape.

Comment: JSON does not support functions.  If you want to send code, you would have to convert it to a string.  What are you actually trying to accomplish because if you change the focus of your question to the real problem here, we can probably actually help you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON does not support functions.

If you want to send code, you would have to convert it to a string.